# Bootstrap 3 Grid col-lg-3 to col-xs-2 i.e. 4x1 to 2x2 grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid

I have a grid of images set out in rows of 4 columns which I want to change to rows of two columns. I thought this would do it: `col-lg-3 col-xs-2`  but it doesn't.

Where am I going wrong?

Code:

```
.test-content{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:lightblue;
}

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-2">
        <div class="test-content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-2">
        <div class="test-content">content</div>
    </div>

<!-- It's like I should have a closing div here for the first row, and open another row just for col-xs-2, but obviously I can't do this for col-lg-3 -->

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-2">
        <div class="test-content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-2">
        <div class="test-content">content</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/41ry7qvk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is working with a grid divided in 12 parts.

col-lg-3 means its width is 3/12. So if you want 2 rows you need col-lg-6.

The same for xs:

col-xs-3 means its width is 3/12. So if you want 2 rows on xs-screen, you need col-xs-6.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap grid system has 12 grids. So instead of `col-xs-2` you should write `col-xs-6` to have 2 images on a row.